# New to regex. Adding a whitespace after all closing tags

Tags: javascript, regex

Totally new to regex. I know how to find all closing tags `/<\/.*?>/g,` but I need to add a whitespace after all closing tags. This just strips all closing tags: `str = str.replace(/<\/.*?>/g, ' ');`

*** Added later

OK, this is the entire script. I can't post it here. You can view it on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bw6yfc7g/3/ I want it to automatically add a whitespace ONLY when a closing and an openings tags run one after the other. In other words when Underline is posted after Bold the tags should look like this: `<b></b> <u></u>` however when they are posted inside each other they should look like this: `<b><u></u></b>` No spaces.

Comment: `str = str.replace(/<\/[^>]+>/g, '$& ');`

Comment: You mentioned tags. This makes me concerned. Regex is not a good tool for matching tagged content such as XML or HTML.

Comment: Is it pure JavaScript or are you using JQuery? Please specify the programming language.

Comment: It's pure javascript.

Comment: And what about the input? Is it just an HTML string, or a part of the loaded document the DOM of which you have access to?

Comment: @Sobrique: You forgot [the obligatory link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/364696).

Comment: @stribizhev It's a function where tags are added onclick to a textarea.So when someone clicks on Bold tab this added `<b></b>` I want it to have a white space after `<\b>`. So far I am unsuccessful to make it work.

Comment: @VitalSigns. Add it to the question.

Comment: Does it mean you want to add a linebreak after the last element node? And yes, please add details to your question.

Comment: @stribizhev OK, I posted more to my original question. Please, check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve that with DOM:

```js
function textNodesUnder(el){
  var n, walk=document.createTreeWalker(el,NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,null,false);
  while(n=walk.nextNode())
  {
      if (n.nodeName !== "MYELT")
      {
          ws_node = document.createTextNode(" ");
          n.parentNode.insertBefore(ws_node, n.nextSibling);
      }
  }
  return el.firstChild.innerHTML;
} 

function addWsNodes(s) {
  var doc = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var wrapper = document.createElement('myelt');
  wrapper.innerHTML = s;
  doc.appendChild( wrapper );
  return textNodesUnder(doc);
}

var s = "This is a <span>test</span>and another<br>test <span>here</span>.";
console.log(addWsNodes(s));
// => This is a <span>test</span> and another<br> test <span>here</span> .
```

Here, the HTML string input is enclosed into a fake element with `myelt` name, then it is added to a document fragment that is passed to the tree walker. There, we only consider element nodes (`SHOW_ELEMENT`), and insert a whitespace element right after it. You may adjust the text contents (insert a tab, or spaces, or linebreaks).

**UPDATE**

Your code is already good, you only have to check if you are inserting something at the end of the text. I added `extra_ws` variable, and assign whitespace to it only if the starting position is the end of existing text. I am adding also a check if we are not at the start of the string:

```
if (startPos === txta.value.length && startPos > 0) ...
```

```js
function addTagSel(tag, idelm) {
  var tag_type = new Array('<', '>');        // for BBCode tag, replace with:  new Array('[', ']');
  var txta = document.getElementById('wmd-input');
  var start = tag_type[0] + tag + tag_type[1];
  var end = tag_type[0] +'/'+ tag +  tag_type[1];
  var IE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;    // this variable is false in all browsers, except IE
  var extra_ws = "";                        // ADDED 
  var offst = 0;
    
  if (IE) {
    var r = document.selection.createRange();
    var tr = txta.createTextRange();
    var tr2 = tr.duplicate();
    tr2.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
    tr.setEndPoint('StartToEnd',tr2);
    var tag_seltxt = start + r.text + end;
    var the_start = txta.value.replace(/[\r\n]/g,'.').indexOf(r.text.replace(/[\r\n]/g,'.'),tr.text.length);
    if (start === txta.value.length && startPos > 0) {      // HERE
      extra_ws = " ";                        // UP TO HERE
      offst = extra_ws.length;
    }
    txta.value = txta.value.substring(0, the_start) + extra_ws + tag_seltxt + txta.value.substring(the_start + tag_seltxt.length, txta.value.length);        // AND HERE

    var pos = txta.value.length - end.length;    // Sets location for cursor position
    tr.collapse(true);
    tr.moveEnd('character', pos + offst);        // start position
    tr.moveStart('character', pos + offst);        // end position
    tr.select();                 // selects the zone
  }
  else if (txta.selectionStart || txta.selectionStart == "0") {
    var startPos = txta.selectionStart;
    var endPos = txta.selectionEnd;
    var tag_seltxt = start + txta.value.substring(startPos, endPos) + end;
    if (startPos === txta.value.length && startPos > 0) {
         extra_ws = " ";
         offst = extra_ws.length;
      }
      txta.value = txta.value.substring(0, startPos) + extra_ws +  tag_seltxt + '\u200C' + txta.value.substring(endPos, txta.value.length);
    
//    txta.value = addWsNodes(txta.value);

    // Place the cursor between formats in #txta
    txta.setSelectionRange((endPos+start.length+offst),(endPos+start.length+offst));
    txta.focus();

  }

  return tag_seltxt;
}
document.getElementById('big').onclick = function() {
  var tag_seltxt = addTagSel('big');
  return tag_seltxt;
}
document.getElementById('b').onclick = function() {
  var tag_seltxt = addTagSel('b');
  return tag_seltxt;
}
document.getElementById('i').onclick = function() {
  var tag_seltxt = addTagSel('i');
  return tag_seltxt;
}
document.getElementById('u').onclick = function() {
  var tag_seltxt = addTagSel('u');
  return tag_seltxt;
}
document.getElementById('del').onclick = function() {
  var tag_seltxt = addTagSel('del');
  return tag_seltxt;
};
```

```css
.edit_button {
display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a class="edit_button" id="big">&nbsp;<span class="titleicon"></span>&nbsp;</a>
<a class="edit_button" id="b">&nbsp;B&nbsp;</a>
<a class="edit_button" id="i">&nbsp;<i>I</i>&nbsp;</a>
<a class="edit_button" id="u">&nbsp;<u>U</u>&nbsp;</a>
<a class="edit_button" id="del">&nbsp;<del>S</del>&nbsp;</a>


<textarea id="wmd-input"></textarea>
```

Comment: Please try using the code snippet I posted. Use your textarea value as `s` variable.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't do anything. I see how it may work, but somehow it's ignoring it altogether.

Comment: Please add details of what you are doing to the post. Step by step, with your code. Best is to provide a snippet.

Comment: OK, this is the entire script. I can't post it here. You can view it on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bw6yfc7g/3/ I want it to automatically add a whitespace ONLY when a closing and an openings tags run one after the other. In other words when Underline is posted after Bold the tags should look like this: `<b></b> <u></u>` however when they are posted inside each other they should look like this: `<b><u></u></b>` No spaces. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Please have a look at my updated answer with your updated fiddle.

Comment: Awesome, but did you notice that the blinking cursor now starts in the wrong place when you generate the tags?

Comment: I added an `offst` variable, now it should set the cursor at the correct place.

Comment: By the way where did the link to updated fiddle go? I can't access it.

Comment: It is now in the answer. Click the Show code snippet at the bottom. Also, I did not test the IE part, I guess you can do it on your side. I can do it when I am back to my desktop.